# Как сделать спавн одного объекта, когда персонаж входит в триггер-Box-коллайдер?

Tags: c#, unity3d

столкнулся с такой проблемой при спавне объектов, когда персонаж находится в триггере, объекты появляются без остановки, до того момента как персонаж не выйдет из коллайдера. Надо сделать так, что бы при входе в триггер появлялся только один объект.
Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObstacles : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Point;
    public GameObject [] Obstacles;
    private int random;
    void Start () {

    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Player") 
        {
            Instantiate (Obstacles[random], Point.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C этим кодом на первый взгляд всё в порядке!  У вас точное нет метода `OnTriggerStay` или подобного? где ещё есть метод `Instantiate`

Comment: Что надо поменять?

Comment: Надо посмотреть еще места во всём проекте, где есть `Instantiate`

Comment: Чир именно надо поменять? Ты можешь рассказать подробнее и показать как надо?

Comment: Я уже два раза написал. Что не ясно во фразе Надо посмотреть еще места во всём проекте, где есть (встречается) слово `Instantiate`? Искал?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего OnTriggerEnter вызывается когда один коллайдер входит в другой. Просто сделайте дополнительную проверку, что объект был создан 1 раз или воспользуйтесь OnTriggerExit.